# Multiple extends in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

I need to do something like that:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-10 custyle">
        @extends('layouts.panel', ['title' => "Categories"] )
        @section('content_panel')
            <table class="table table-striped custab">
                 ...
            </table>
        @stop
@stop
```

Thing is my final HTML is not well formed.

What should I do to import several partials so I don't have to repeat my code.

Tx!

Comment: It would be useful if you could include all of the code in your example as you've got unclosed elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your code slightly if you want to use the above. You'll also need to use @include instead of @extends.

Something like the below

```
@include('layouts.panel', ['title' => "Categories"] )
```

Your final code could look like ...

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md-10 custyle">
            @include('layouts.panel', ['title' => "Categories"] )
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('content_panel')
    <table class="table table-striped custab">
             ...
    </table>
@endsection
```

Comment: but inside my panel, I need to put dynamic content, that's why I think include doesn t suit very well

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but this unfortunately does not work as you expect it to. What you can use are blade components to help achieve what you intend with your query.

You can create a component and save a spot for your content. For example, lets say you have panel.blade.php

```
<div class='layout-panel'>
    {{$slot}}
</div>
```

Then you can use it as a component and fill that spot with your content

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-10 custyle">
        @component('layouts.panel')

            <table class="table table-striped custab">
                 ...
            </table>
        @endcomponent
@endsection
```

Hope this helps!